# BSoD after modifying bcedit hypervisorlaunchtype

Tags: windows-10, bsod, hyper-v

So I was trying to run a Virtual Machine though Virtual Box but now my computer won't even start. I was getting the error `raw-mode unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V` and I found a thread which recommended I ran `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` When I first ran bcedit, there was no `hypervisorlaunchtype` present. I did so and now when I try to restart my computer, I sometimes get a BSoD saying `MACHINE CHECK EXCEPTION` and sometimes just showing this: [Windows loading circle not moving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYOjb.jpg) The loading sign starts moving, then after a couple of seconds, it just stops and stands there. The BSoD only occurred once so far and restarting doesn't help. I am using Windows 10 Home and my processor supports Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x).
CPU: i7-6850K
RAM: 16GB 2400Mhz
Motherboard: MSI X99A guard-pro. Sometimes the computer attempts an Automatic repair but it always fails with the BSoD. I am not provided with a recovery environment

Comment: Does your processor support VT-X or AMD-V.  Please update your question to include this vital information required to answer your question.  You should also indicate if Hyper-V was even installed if you modified the boot configuration data without first removing the feature, that could explain your problems.  Additionally, indicate if you are using, Windows 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: As I stated in my question; hypervisorlaunchtype was not present when I ran `bcedit` the first time. Does this mean it wasn't installed? I have updated my question to contain the other missing information.

Comment: It appears you ran the incorrect command.  You are going to have to manually modify the boot configuration data entry for your Windows.  This will require a Windows installation disk.  Within WinRE, you need to run `bcdedit`, and provide the output.

Comment: If you are not being offered a recovery environment after multiple failed boots, this problem is significantly tougher to fix, hopefully, that is the case.  Update your question.